# Property of the maximum value for a fraction

Tags: optimization, summation, real-numbers, fractions

Suppose that I want to maximize a quantity
\begin{equation*}\frac{f_1+f_2}{f_3+f_4}\end{equation*}
where $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4\in\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$ have to satisfy some given conditions.

Suppose that I know $f'_1,f'_2,f'_3,f'_4\in\mathbb{R_{\geq 0}}$ such that they satisfy my conditions and such that:

- $\frac{f'_1}{f'_3}$ is the maximum value of $\frac{f_1}{f_3}$ under my conditions;
- $\frac{f'_2}{f'_4}$ is the maximum value of $\frac{f_2}{f_4}$ under my conditions.

Can I say that \begin{equation*}\frac{f'_1+f'_2}{f'_3+f'_4}\end{equation*}is the maximum value of\begin{equation*}\frac{f_1+f_2}{f_3+f_4}\end{equation*}under my conditions? If yes, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My other answer gives a counter-example, in this answer I give an alternative approach for such maximizations. This is related to a set of "renewal optimization" problems I had thought about in this paper (my answer here is related to Lemma 5):

http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/renewal-optimization.pdf

Suppose we have the general problem: 
\begin{align}
\mbox{Maximize:} \quad & \frac{f_1+f_2}{f_3+f_4}\\
\mbox{Subject to:} \quad & (f_1, f_3) \in A \\
& (f_2, f_4) \in B
\end{align}
where $A$ and $B$ are given subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  For simplicity, let's assume $A$ and $B$ are compact subsets, and all vectors in set $B$ have strictly positive components (this ensures a maximum exists, and we do not have divide-by-zero issues).  Let $(f_1^*, f_3^*)\in A, (f_2^*, f_4^*)\in B$ be a (possibly non-unique) optimum for the above problem, and define $\theta^*$ as the maximum objective value: 
$$ \theta^* = \frac{f_1^*+f_2^*}{f_3^*+f_4^*}$$
For each $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, define the function:
$$ h(\theta) = \max_{(f_1, f_3) \in A, (f_2,f_4)\in B}[(f_1+f_2)-\theta(f_3+f_4)]$$
The interesting thing is that for each given $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, the $h(\theta)$ function is easy to compute by *separately* maximizing $(f_1-\theta f_3)$ over all $(f_1,f_3) \in A$ and $(f_2-\theta f_4)$ over all $(f_2,f_4)\in B$.

Claim 1:

- $h(\theta)>0$ if and only if $\theta < \theta^*$.
- $h(\theta) < 0$ if and only if $\theta > \theta^*$.
- $h(\theta) = 0$ if and only if $\theta = \theta^*$.

This claim means that if we can *bracket* the optimal value $\theta^*$ by some known upper and lower bounds, then we can perform a bisection search by testing different $\theta$ values, getting new upper and lower bounds on $\theta^*$, and zero in on the optimal $\theta^*$ exponentially fast. Each step of the search requires a simple separate maximization.

Now let $T_{min}$ be the minimum value of $f_3+f_4$ over all $(f_1,f_3)\in A$ and all $(f_2,f_4)\in B$, and note by assumption that $T_{min}>0$.

Claim 2: Fix $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. Let $(\hat{f}_1(\theta), \hat{f}_3(\theta))\in A, (\hat{f}_2(\theta),\hat{f}_4(\theta))\in B$ be maximizers corresponding to the definition of $h(\theta)$. Then: 
$$ \frac{\hat{f}_1(\theta)+\hat{f}_2(\theta)}{\hat{f}_3(\theta) + \hat{f}_4(\theta)} \leq \theta^* \leq \frac{\hat{f}_1(\theta)+\hat{f}_2(\theta)}{\hat{f}_3(\theta) + \hat{f}_4(\theta)} + \frac{|h(\theta)|}{T_{min}} $$ 
This means that if we find a value $\theta$ such that $h(\theta) \approx 0$, then the greedy maximizations to find $h(\theta)$ result in a solution that is a close approximation to the solution of the original problem.

---

The proof of claims 1 and 2 are similar and are related to the proofs I gave in the above paper. Here is a quick proof of Claim 2:

Proof (Claim 2): The first inequality holds by definition of $\theta^*$ as maximizer of the desired ratio.  To prove the second inequality, define
\begin{align}
n &= \hat{f}_1(\theta) + \hat{f}_2(\theta)\\
d &= \hat{f}_3(\theta) + \hat{f}_4(\theta) \\
n^* &= f_1^* + f_2^*\\
d^* &= f_3^* + f_4^*
\end{align}
Notice that $d\geq T_{min}>0, d^*\geq T_{min}>0$, and by definitions: 
$$ n - \theta d  = h(\theta) \geq n^* - \theta d^* $$
So
$$ \theta^* = \frac{n^*}{d^*} \leq \theta + \frac{h(\theta)}{d^*} = \frac{n-h(\theta)}{d} + \frac{h(\theta)}{d^*} = \frac{n}{d} - \frac{h(\theta)}{d} + \frac{h(\theta)}{d^*}$$
and the right-hand-side is less than or equal to $n/d + |h(\theta)|/T_{min}$ if $h(\theta)\geq 0$, likewise when $h(\theta)<0$. $\Box$

Comment: Thank you so much for your beautiful answer!

Answer (score 1):

Generally no, consider the example:

\begin{align}
\mbox{Maximize:} \quad & \frac{f_1+f_2}{f_3+f_4}\\
\mbox{Subject to:} \quad &  (f_1, f_3) \in \{(200, 100), (1, 1)\}\\
& (f_2, f_4)\in \{(100,1)\}
\end{align}
In this example, there is only one choice for $(f_2, f_4)$, but two choices for $(f_1, f_3)$.  We can see that the choice $(f_1, f_3) = (200,100)$ maximizes the individual ratio of $f_1/f_3$, but is *not* the maximizing choice for this problem: 
$$ \frac{200+100}{100+1} < \frac{1+100}{1+1} $$

Comment: There is still hope, if you are interested I was about to type up a more detailed alternative approach for such maximizations. Or, perhaps you could give more context and/or specify the conditions, as Tal mentions in the other answer.

Comment: Yes please! I am very much interested!

Comment: I am actually interested in finding the conditions such that my claim holds.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the conditions. If your conditions allow smaller values of $f_3,f_4$, for instance, say $\alpha<f_3,\beta<f_4$, then $(f_1+f_2)/(\alpha+\beta)$ is greater than your value.

You could give more insight about these conditions to examine further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can not use $(f_1+f_2)/(\alpha+\beta)$ because I'm assuming that $f_1'/f_3'$ maximizes $f_1/f_3$ and that $f_2'/f_4'$ maximizes $f_2/f_4$ under the given conditions. Your example does not hold for this assumption.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Is it necessary to maximize $f_1/f_3$ and $f_2/f_4$ and your expression simultaneously? If it is, please edit the question.

Comment: This is not what I said. Please read again my question.

Comment: I didn't claim you said it. Please read again my answer

Comment: I didn't claim that you claimed that I said it. Please read again my answer.